# MAVEN to change the file structure while execution of Unpack

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, unpack

I my CI setup I have deploy the zip file from nexus to tomcat server.
Below is my Deployment POM.

```
<execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>//</groupId>
               <artifactId>//</artifactId>
               <version>//version</version>
               <classifier>bin</classifier>
               <type>zip</type>
               <overWrite>true</overWrite>
               <outputDirectory>//tomcat folder </outputDirectory>
               <includes>**/*.war,appconf/dev/*.properties</includes> 
               </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
            <includes>**/*.properties</includes>
             </configuration>
        </execution>
```

i provided includes and property file under dev as below

```
<includes>**/*.war,test/dev/*.properties</includes>
```

So it creates a test folder and place the property files inside.I want to skip the dev folder but the property file has to copied and put directly inside the test fodler.
As of now the tomcat directory looks like test\dev\test.properties.
but I need to change test\test.properties when unpack the zip file.

help me to resolve this issue using MAVEN.

Comment: Which plugin do you use? Furthermore to deploy things to a application server or tomcat like things you should use things like [cargo-mave2-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).